# Not equals operator not working in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B that contains the same Id (is not a primary key in the two tables) , and I would like to get only the data that exist in Table A .

Table A:

```
Id

1
2
555
6
```

Table B

```
Id

1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Query statement

```sql
select distinct o.Id
from  Table A o,Table B ot
where o.isActive=1 and not(ot.Id=o.Id)
```

This will return the same data that exists in Table A, but the expected result should be :

```
Id

555
 6
```

How can I get this works?

Comment: I don't think you want a cartesian product. Try `SELECT DISTINCT o.Id FROM TableA WHERE o.IsActive = 1 AND o.Id NOT IN (SELECT ot.Id FROM TableB ot);`

Comment: Your solution worked for me , you can put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `,` join syntax, it was deprecated *30 year*s ago. Your current query is the same as this:

```
select distinct o.Id
from  TableA o
join TableB ot on o.isActive=1 and ot.Id <> o.Id
```

This will return all rows from `TableA` where there exist rows that *do not* match this one. This is not what you are trying to do. **Instead, use `EXCEPT`:**

```sql
select o.Id
    from TableA o
    where o.isActive=1
except
select ot.Id
    from Table B ot;
```

**`EXCEPT` implies a `DISTINCT`.** If you would like all rows from `TableA` including duplicates then you need `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
select o.Id
from TableA o
where o.isActive=1
    and not exists (select 1
        from Table B ot
        where ot.Id = oId);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution before posting the question but it does not to be working when the number of columns is not the same when comparing the statement before `except` and the statement after

Comment: In that case you need `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

Below is one approach. I also added a condition to ensure there is a legit value in the Id field in Table B since you said it's not an identity column.

```sql
select distinct Id
from Table A
where Id not in
    (select Id
    from Table B
    where Id > 0)
```

Comment: Please note that `not in` has issues dealing with nullable columns and will not return correct results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: That's why I included where id > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists:

select distinct o.Id from  [Table A] o
where o.isActive=1 and
not exists (select 1 from [Table B] ot where o.Id =ot.Id)
This will select unique Id from [Table A] which doesn't exist in [Table B]. If Id column doesn't have duplicate value in [Table A] then you an remove ditinct from the query.